# Why does MsBuild Publish create extra App.exe file at root of publish folder

Tags: c#, msbuild

When I publish my solution from Visual Studio my publish folder looks like:

```
- Application Files/
---- App_1_0_0_0
------- All the build files
------- App.exe
- App.application
```

When I publish using msbuild from powershell:

```
 & MSBuild -m AppSolution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /t:publish /p:PublishDir="C:\projects\AppSolutionFolder\Publish\\" | Out-Default
```

My Publish folder looks like:

```
- Application Files/
---- App_1_0_0_0
------- All the build files
------- App.exe
- App.application
- App.exe
```

Why is MsBuild generating an extra EXE at the root of my publish folder?

**Edit 1**
So I have discovered through more logging that there is a step in the ClickOnce deployment creation that is causing this duplicate EXE to be copied over: **_DeploymentComputeClickOnceManifestInfo**

However I can't find any way to stop this step from running nor can I find any documentation on why MSBuild runs this step and VS does not (well to be clear, it does run the step, but the step doesn't do anything).

From the logs it looks like the Publish process is completely different when done in VS2019 vs from MSBuild.  They do things in a different order, they reference different build targets and clearly, the output is different.  Is there any way to get MSBuild to behave, as it should, like Publish from VS2019?

Comment: Set `<UseAppHost>false</UseAppHost>` in project file, it should disable creation of `.exe` file

Comment: @JL0PD Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately it did not work.  I even tried adding the UseAppHost to every combination of Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)', still generates the exe :(

Comment: Setting <SelfContained>false</SelfContained> also didn't work.

Comment: That's strange, because when I create new project `dotnet new console -n PublishTest` and set `<UseAppHost>false</UseAppHost>` inside `PropertyGroup` and publish it with `dotnet publish` it doesn't create `.exe` file. Either there's something wrong with your project file or msbuild publishes differently when invoked directly